What is that black border around the edges of the metal base of a laptop keyboard?
On literally every notebook keyboard I've ever taken apart for cleaning and/or repair, I've seen this black border on the front side of the metal plate, just under the membrane layer. Quite difficult to scrape, it comes off fairly easily with acetone. On the back side there is no such edge.

(source: YouTube video)
I have always tried to preserve it when wiping, but it is hard enough because there is plenty of key hooks on this side. So now I have two questions:

What is the reason for this border? Is it just an adhesive for the membrane layer or does it have some other, say, insulating purpose?

Can it be removed without affecting the functionality of the keyboard immediately or in the future?



why do you want to remove it?

@jsotola I don't want to, but it would be much easier to ignore it when cleaning, since then I could just dip the plate into the liquid cleanser.

I could just dip the plate into the liquid cleanser ... why can't you dip it? ... what cleanser are you using?

@jsotola Acetone and isopropanol. This makes the border soft and peeling off.

@cher-nov acetone is a solvent that dissolves many types of plastic ... don't use it for cleaning ... use orange oil for removing gummy residue

@jsotola I know, and I don't use it for plastic parts - only for metal ones like this plate.
